# How to fix/troubleshoot React Express 404 Error with static site?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, fetch

I have an input that calls this submit function onSubmit:

```
  const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setfruit(item);
    console.log("sent")
    fetch('/api/tasks/add', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ Name: item.Name,Quantity: item.Quantity, edit: item.edit }),
    }).then(() => {
      setItem(itemd)
      getTasks();
    });
  };
```

and my route:

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    const { Name, Price, edit } = req.body;
    const newTask = new Task({ Name, Price, edit });

    newTask.save()
        .then(task => res.json(task))
        .catch(err => res.json(500, err));
});
```

Heres my index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const routeTasks = require('./src/routes/tasks');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/tasks', routeTasks, (req, res) => res.sendStatus(401));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + './client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port);

console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
```

Every time I call the onSubmit function, I get a 404 error. I can't tell why.
[image: error message]

I used this repo as a guide for creating my express server but for some reason when I switch the underlying React app it stops working.
https://github.com/jmsv/simple-mern

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured in your React app to forward `/api` requests to your Express app?

Comment: Try checking that the localhost port number you are making the request to, matches the port number that your express app is listening on. It appears you are making the request to `3000` but express is listening on `5000`.

Comment: @rexessilfie the example project OP linked to uses a [proxy](https://github.com/jmsv/simple-mern/blob/master/client/package.json#L5). Whether or not OP has kept that configuration is the real question

Comment: @Phil let me check.

Comment: Ahh. I see. That is a great catch @Phil! Keeping the proxy configuration [here](https://github.com/jmsv/simple-mern/blob/ca5118a0c1fe008bada07e32d4c8355e65469e4b/client/package.json#L5) as in the example project may solve things then.

Comment: @Phil I added the proxy setting. I now get a 500 error

Comment: Progress! Check your Express app's logs and also the response body in your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel. I'm sure you can solve it from there

Comment: Hmm, you're posting an object with `Name`, `Quantity` and `edit` properties yet your backend expects `Name`, `Price` and `edit`. That's probably the source of your 500 error.

Comment: @Phil I changed Price to quantity and still have this:
message: "Task validation failed: Quantity: Path `Quantity` is required."
name: "ValidationError"
_message: "Task validation failed"

Comment: But, I did give Quantity in the post request

Comment: _"I changed Price to quantity"_... should that be `Quantity` (with a capital "Q"). JavaScript symbols are case sensitive. If you're still having trouble, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68810535/edit) to update the code

Comment: @Phil I got it, I just gave lowercase quantity in the comment not in the code. I restarted the express server and now it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236070/discussion-between-corgiraptor-and-phil).

Answer (score -1):

Per Phil's comment, my issue was that the example Repo I was going off of used a React proxy which I hadn't configured in my own app. Once I added that to the package.json file, it worked.